# Do... While loop counter implementation not working

Tags: c#, do-loops

I created a program in C# (Console Application), which prompts the user to enter the answer to "2+2=?", if its right a message pops up "Well done", if not then "Please try again". What I am trying to do is make the program tell the user how many guesses/attempts they have made before getting the correct answer.

This is what I have done so far

```
class Program
{
    public static int correct_answer, counter,  user_answer, counterUpdated;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        correct_answer = 4;

        do 
        {
            counter = 1;
            counterUpdated = counter++;

            Console.WriteLine("2+2= ?");
            user_answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (user_answer != correct_answer)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong, try againg" + " this is your " + counterUpdated + " try.");
            }
        } while (user_answer != correct_answer); // The code will keep looping until the user prompts the correct answer 

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Well Done! you did it in this amount of guesses " + counterUpdated);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If someone could tell me how to make the counter thing work, that would be great.

Comment: do not declare variables as static fields. its not a good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweaked a bit, and this should work :)

```
class Program
{
    public static int correct_answer, counter,  user_answer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        correct_answer = 4;
        counter = 0;
        do 
        {

            counter++;

            Console.WriteLine("2+2= ?");
            user_answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (user_answer != correct_answer)
            {

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong, try againg" + " this is your " + counter+ " try.");

            }



        } while (user_answer != correct_answer); // The code will keep looping until the user prompts the correct answer 
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Well Done! you did it in this amount of guesses " + counter);
        Console.ReadLine();



    }
}
```

What i did was i removed the `counterUpdated` variable and had the `counter` variable do all the counting work :)

Hope it helped :)

Comment: replace `counterUpdated` with `counter`... you removed `counterUpdated` but you forgot to replace the one with `counter`. look at your code in Console.WriteLine

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary yeah :) fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

You always set `counter` to 1 at the start of the loop, then immediately `counterUpdated = counter++;` (which is a bit odd anyway...).
Just do it with one counter that you initialize outside the loop and increment inside the loop.

```
int guessNumber = 0;
do {
    guessNumber++;
    // ...
```